# How to sort GTLQueryDrive items by folders first, name, size, date

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

To get the items, i do like this:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' IN parents and trashed=false", folderID];
query.fields = @"files(mimeType, id, name, size, createdTime)";
[self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
GTLDriveFileList *files,
      NSError *error) {
}];
```

But the files and folders scattered about and not sorted by name.
So how to do it without manually sorting?

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529474/google-drive-api-not-returning-results-by-descending-order-of-number-of-occurren), you can use the [`orderBy`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#parameters) query parameter which has a value of `string` to order the Documents List Feed by certain criteria or keys. Valid keys are `createdDate`, `folder`, `lastViewedByMeDate`, `modifiedByMeDate`, `modifiedDate`, `quotaBytesUsed`, `recency`, `sharedWithMeDate`, `starred`, and `title`. Each key sorts ascending by default, but may be reversed with the `desc` modifier.

Example usage: `?orderBy=folder,modifiedDate desc,title`. Please note that there is a current limitation for users with approximately one million files in which the requested sort order is ignored.

You can also check these related SO questions:

- [Google drive API - List orderBy does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726416/google-drive-api-list-orderby-does-not-work)
- [Get files list in a folder order by Modified date desending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827607/get-files-list-in-a-folder-order-by-modified-date-desending)
- [Sort files by creation date - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977664/sort-files-by-creation-date-ios)

Comment: This is the perfect answer.